# my WebSocket php Does not work when 2 or more person send request

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, server, centos

I have centos 6.8
When two or more concurrent users submit multiple entries socket does not work

console write :
"WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state"

When a person uses it .not There is no problem

where is my problem ?

updaete-------->
We are working on a project, in every second we want to take data from specific URL “server a”, and we won’t any late in the time even a second, also we don’t have access to that server. We used WebSocket, the problem is when few users connect to website at the moment, multi requests will be sent to “server a”, and because requests at the same time, just one of them will be answered, to solve this problem we decided to use “Cache” but it has high risk.

Is there any way when WebSocket progress will have a break less than a second?
If you have a suggestion for this problem please tell us.
Project information and Server - Laravel 5.2

https://github.com/BrainBoxLabs/brain-socket
https://github.com/BrainBoxLabs/brain-socket-js
Apache Version 2.4
CentOs 6.8

Comment: You really should add more information here. What http server are you using? Show the essential part of the PHP code as well!

Comment: Generally speaking, a socket can only deal with 1 person at a time, which is why, typically, a listening socket's only responsibility is to create a thread to handle an incoming request. If you have 2 people trying to connect to a listening socket at the same time one will either be queued or dropped.

Comment: update my post more information